MongoDB Compass connection password missing when using I3 WM
When saving a connection on Compass and come back to it later, I found that the password is missing. I have to type it again. This issue only happens when running i3 wm. It doesn't happen on KDE Plama for example.
example
saving: mongodb://username:password@host:port/db
when I click on the connection later I find the URI like this:
mongodb://username@host:port/db (the password is gone)
What should I do to prevent this from happening on i3?
I tried installing different versions of Compass and compiling from source but no difference.

The environment variable XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP is not set, or it's set to something other than what's needed (e.g., set to Hyprland or another value). MongoDB Compass and similar apps (which use Electron) rely on this variable to handle certain desktop-related features, such as storing passwords using the system's keyring.
Reference: https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/issues/1880#issuecomment-2043543755
By setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP to a value that Compass recognizes (like GNOME), the app will work correctly, and the password won't disappear. This trick forces Compass to use a known desktop environment configuration, which allows the password to be saved properly. But ensure that you already installed the keyrings. e.g. gnome-keyring for GNOME and it's running in the background by set exec --no-startup-id /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh in your i3 config
